# Are Israeli and Thai sockets accidentally compatible?

Tags: thailand, israel, power, palestine

It looks like the Thai "Type-O" plugs have the same specs as Israeli "Type H", and the plug looks similar, but "upside-down":

Type H:
[image]

Type O:
[image]

Can you actually plug one kind into the other?

Comment: FWIW, I don't think I've ever actually seen that Type O plug in Thailand, they use a motley mix but US style Type B is the most common.  (But at 220V, not 110V!)

Answer (score 7):

### No, they aren't.

From reading [Power plug & outlet Type H](https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/h/) and [Power plug & outlet Type O](https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/o/) it appears that they are not compatible.  The latter link explicitly says

> Although they look similar, type O plugs are not interchangeable with
>   the Israeli type H

Also from [Israel SI32 (Type H)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#Israel_SI32_(Type_H)) it says

> The pre-1989 system has three flat pins in a Y-shape, with line and
>   neutral 19 mm (0.75 in) apart. The plug is rated at 16 A. In 1989 the
>   standard was revised, with three round 4.5 mm (0.177 in) pins in the
>   same locations

And [Thai 3 pin plug TIS 166-2549](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#Thai_3_pin_plug_TIS_166-2549) says

> The plug has two round power pins 4.8 mm in diameter and 19 mm in
>   length, insulated for 10 mm and spaced 19 mm apart, with an earthing
>   pin of the same diameter and 21.4 mm in length, located 11.89 mm from
>   the line connecting the two power pins

There is a difference in the pin diameters.  Depending on which way you are trying to plug things in you could potentially either jam things in or have a loose connection.  There may be enough mechanical play to do this, but I would not recommend doing it.

---

And I love this quote from the World Standards website (above)

> Type H plugs are among the most dangerous ones in the world: the
>   prongs are not insulated (i.e. the pin shanks do not have a black
>   covering towards the plug body like type C, G, I, L or N plugs), which
>   means that if a type H plug is pulled halfway out, its prongs are
>   still connected to the socket!

Comment: 1. A .3mm diameter difference is quite possibly within the tolerance of a socket's plastic... how sure are you that it won't fit? 2. I don't understand your latter quote. Even with the covering toward the black body (like in C plugs) - if you pull a plug half-way out, the part that's still connected to the socket is the exposed end.

Comment: @einpoklum It's not a brilliantly written statement. The part that isn't stated is that the live pins then extend out of the socket for you to accidentally bridge with a dropped metal object (or your fingers).

Comment: @einpoklum If you plug the smaller diameter pin into the larger diameter hole you risk causing arcing in the socket - especially in an older socket that is already worn.  That is a fire hazard.  Plugging the larger into the smaller could damage the socket to the point that it causes arcing for the expected pin size.  So yes, you can use a hammer to make the plug fit, but that doesn't mean you should

Comment: @origimbo I understood it perfectly, but then again understanding things like this is a part of my day job :D

Comment: UK and Euro plugs are also incompatible officially, but you plenty of people still use their Euro devices in the UK without incident :)

Comment: @JonathanReez And I've seen friends in Russia turning lights on and off by twisting and un-twisting live wires.  It all depends on how far you are willing to go!

Comment: @JonathanReez: How do you mean? Round peg in square hole -style?

Comment: @einpoklum you first insert a thin narrow object into the earthing pin, which unblocks the power pins. Then you insert your European plug.

Comment: @PeterM: 1. Of course there's a theoretical hazard, but: 2. We're talking about a .3mm difference here. The metal on the other side will probably  accept either of them fine, because it has to apply some counter-pressure anyway; the plastic would likely also budge. The point is that 3. You're speculating based on the official description of the socket types, not empirical data.

Comment: @origimbo: So, this would be true for sockets that are not indented. I just checked (with a tester... don't worry) and there is a 2-3mm gap if you go perpendicular, maybe 5mm gap if you angle it just right, for something to go in and bridge the pins. So, this is still definitely dangerous - but only if you have some kind of piece of metal; not for your fingers. Not to mention that when you hold the plug your fingers are kind of busy.

Comment: I frequently put plug type J (Swiss, 4.0 mm) into type E (French, 4.8 mm), which works without any issues (the plug will tilt down due to gravity, which gives a good-enough connection). The opposite however is impossible due to the different diameters. 0.8 mm is however significantly more than 0.3...

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer says Wikipedia claims they are not compatible.

From the information I can find online you have two potential issues.

1. Pin size, according to Wikiepdia the pins on the Thai plug are 4.8mm while those on the Isralli plug are 4.5mm.
2. The earth pin offset appears to be different. Wikipedia doesn't mention an earth pin offset for the Israeli plug but https://www.plugsocketmuseum.nl/ConfigEarthSockets1.html says it is 9.8mm. Meanwhile wikipedia and the source it cites https://web.archive.org/web/20160707011303/https://law.resource.org/pub/th/ibr/th.cs.166.e.2549.pdf says the offset of the Thai plus is 11.89mm.

The first issue may well be "within tolerance". Indeed at  https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31554/is-there-continued-movement-towards-unification-of-electric-power-wall-socket-pl the poster claims that "type F" plugs (which also have 4.8mm pins) will fit in Israeli sockets.

However the second issue seems more fatal. The difference in offset is more than a third of the diameter of the pin. Unless the socket is an explicit multi-standard socket that seems unlikely to be within tolerance.

Comment: I wish we had someone to just go ahead and try it :-)

Comment: ""type F" plugs (which also have 4.8mm pins) will fit in Israeli sockets." <- From frequent experience, they do. But: 1. You don't get grounding of course. 2. You need to squeeze them into place and pull hard to release them.